# Show Author.name in custom XSL for blog post

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, xslt

I've been attempting to modify the XSLT on the blog posts to show the authors photo.

I've managed to get the photo showing by changing the 'Created By' column to the value "Person (with picture)" and using @Author.picture.

However, changing this column makes [@Author.span show the user's name *AND* picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvX8Y.png), which i don't want - I would like to display them separately.

@Author.name didn't work, so I'm thinking it may be called something else.

Is there a property of "@Author" that will display just their full name as a hyperlink to their profile?

*Update: I've tried out additional possibilities and @author.title displays the name, but not as a click-able link.*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use two person\group columns for each item, one to take the picture from and another to take the name from.
So simply add a second person\group column called AuthorName (when you create it choose Name only and also not to add it to your content type and default view). 
You can use a workflow to automatically set your AuthorName column to have the same value of the actual author user name.
It's not ideal but I previously used this workaround and it worked for me.